# Can I open an NSMenu programatically?

Tags: macos, menubar, nsmenu

Like the title says, I want to automatically open the menu at certain intervals. Preferably from within the program itself, as I am sure I could do something manually with applescripts+cron, which I don't want to use.

I am talking about a menu/button/whatever from the OSX menubar. Just to be clear. No custom views, just a plain nsmenu.

Answer (score 3):

For opening an NSStatusItem menu, I found it easier to call the `performClick` method on the button belonging to the `NSStatusItem`. That way I didn't have to worry about properly passing an event or view to `popUpContextMenu`. Something like this:

```
statusItem.button?.performClick(nil)
```

Comment: It will look like this: `statusItem.button?.performClick(nil)`

Answer (score 1):

You can programatically show an `NSMenu` by calling:

```
[NSMenu popUpContextMenu:YOUR_MENU withEvent:MOUSE_EVENT forView:YOUR_VIEW]
```

To construct the event you can use `NSEvent`'s `+mouseEventWithType:location:modifierFlags:timestamp:windowNumber:context:eventNumber:clickCount:pressure:`

Note: if your menu is an `NSStatusItem` menu, you will have to set the item's view to be able to popUp the menu.